# How to use multiple key for the same value in an Swift Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

How can I store user records into Swift `Dictionary`, but index them by two type of keys: `userID` and `firstName`? Is it possible?

If a value is removed both expression `users[aUserID]` and `user[aFirstName]` should return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** have multiple keys for the same value, consider this example:

```
class Value {
    var name = "John"
}

var dictionary: [String: Value] = [:]

var value1 = Value()

dictionary["key1"] = value1
dictionary["key2"] = value1

value1.name = "Theresa"

dictionary["key1"]?.name // "Theresa"
dictionary["key2"]?.name // "Theresa"
```

For the second part of your question:

> If value is removed both expression users[aUserID] and user[aFirstName] should return nil.

When you do this `dict["key1"] = nil`, the value for the `key2` is still there and would be `value1`, so you could create a custom `subscript` that would handle that by finding identical `values` in the `dictionary`.

Comment: For the second part, IMO, it would be easier to wrap [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable) with `.weakMemory` value pointer option in your class.

Comment: @user28434 Bare in mind that the `NSMapTable` is a generic Objective-C class. OP asked for the **swift** `Dictionary` with a **swift** tag on the question. Using this would also limit you to the `NSObject` types only. Furthermore, to use the `NSMapTable` that way, you would end up with extending it with a custom `subscript` anyway.

Comment: That's why i've told to **wrap** it. Like in Swift clas. Take ObjC type NSMapTable and wrap it in Swift type. And, ofc, it will require to define own `subscript`.

Comment: Also, since Swift 3.0, limitation to NSObject subclass is irrelevant, because any type now can be boxed into SwiftValue under the hood, which is seen as NSObject subclass by ObjC code.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries don't care about unique values, they only care about unique keys. So you can have as many identical values in a dictionary as you like, as long as their keys are all different.

The way I would approach your problem is by hiding all the necessary logic to keep the dictionary keys in sync in a wrapper class:

```
struct User {
    let userId: Int
    let firstName: String
    // more user properties
}

class UserDict {

    private var dict = [String: User]()

    subscript(key: String) -> User? {
        return dict[key]
    }

    subscript(key: Int) -> User? {
        return dict["\(key)"]
    }

    func add(_ user: User) {
        dict[user.firstName] = user
        dict["\(user.userId)"] = user
    }

    func remove(forKey key: String) {
        if let user = dict[key] {
            dict.removeValue(forKey: user.firstName)
            dict.removeValue(forKey: "\(user.userId)")
        }
    }

    func remove(forKey key: Int) {
        remove(forKey: "\(key)")
    }

    var count: Int {
        return dict.count / 2
    }
}
```